# Regex to split up string of CPU usage without percentage

Tags: regex, grafana, telegraf

Is it possible to get the result just first two digits without % in the first group. Iam using Telegraf with Grafana.

Example:

```
5 Secs ( 22.3463%) 60 Secs ( 25.677%) 300 Secs ( 21.3522%)
```

Result:

```
22
```

I found out this regex in the similar topic, but it's return bad format for me :

```
^\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)\)$
```

Comment: What regex variant are you using, (python, javascript, some specific software)? Grouping works significantly different in each case, as well as other features like lookbacks and references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your pattern to use a single capturing group by relocating the parenthesis around the digits only for the first occurrence.

You can omit the second and third capture groups as you don't need them.

```
^\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?%\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)$

                      ^   ^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQVSGx/1)

Or you might use a named capture group, for example `digits`

```
^\s*\d+\s+Secs\s*\(\s*(?P<digits>\d+)(?:\.\d+)?%\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)$
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+(\d+)(?:\.\d+%)?\)(?:\s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\))*
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/q5HgGw/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+          ##From starting of value matching digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by space(s) Secs spaces ( spaces.
(\d+)                        ##Creating 1st and only capturing group where we have digits in it.
(?:\.\d+%)?\)                ##In a non-capturing group matching dot digits % ) keeping it optional followed by )
(?:                          ##Creating a non-capturing group here.
   \s+\d+\s+Secs\s+\(\s+\d+  ##matching spaces digits spaces Secs spaces ( spaces digits
   (?:\.\d+)?                ##In a non-capturing group matching dot digits keeping it optional.
   %\)                       ##matching % followed by ) here.
)*                           ##Closing very first non-capturing group, and matching its 0 or more occurrences.
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the 1st occurrence you're after, wouldn't the following work?

```
/secs\s*\(\s*(\d+)/i
```